# SAS and do loop

Tags: sas

I'm writing a program in SAS.

Here's the dataset I have:

```
id huuse days  
1   0   4  
1   0   3  
1   1   12    
1   1   1  
1   2   15  
2   1   13  
2   0   16  
2   1   18  
2   0   44
```

For each ID, I want to delete the record if variable `huuse` ne 1, until I get to the first `huuse=1`. Then I want to keep that record and all subsequent records for that id, no matter what value `huuse` is. So for `id=1`, I want to delete the first two records than keep all records for `id=1` starting with the 3rd record. For `id=2`, the first record has `huuse=1`, so I want to keep all records for `id=2`.

The data set I want should look like this:

```
id huuse days  
1   0   4  
1   0   3  
1   1   12  
1   1   1  
1   2   15  
2   1   13  
2   0   16  
2   1   18  
2   0   44
```

I tried this code, but it removes **all** records that have huuse ne 1.

```
data want;  
set have;  
by id;  
do until (huuse=1);  
if huuse = 1 then LEAVE;            
if huuse ne 1 then DELETE;  
END;  
run;
```

I've tried several variations of do loops, but they all do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The `DATA` step is a program with an implicit loop that reads every record of the data set specified in the `SET` statement.  Any program data vector (pdv) variables not coming from the data set are, by default, reset to missing at the top of the implicit loop.  You change that behavior using a `RETAIN` statement to name variables that should not get reset.

So, in your problem you have two situations when a *tracking* variable is needed.  The variable will track the state of the condition *Have I seen `huuse=1` yet in this group ?*.  Call this variable `one_flag`

- `RETAIN one_flag;` so **you** control when it's value changes
- At the start of a `BY` group `one_flag` needs to be reset to false (`0`)
- When `huuse` is first seen as `1` set the flag to true (`1`)

Example:

```
data want(drop=one_flag);
  set have;
  by id;

  retain one_flag 0;

  if first.id then one_flag = 0;

  if not one_flag and huuse = 1 then one_flag = 1;

  if one_flag then OUTPUT;   * want all rows in group starting at first huuse=1;
run;
```

You can place the `SET` and `BY` statement ***inside*** an explicit `DO` and that changes the operating behavior of the program, especially if the explicit loop is terminated according to a `LAST.<var>` automatic variable.  Such a loop is commonly called a DOW loop by SAS programmers.  There is no phrase *DOW loop* in the SAS documentation.

Example:

```
data want;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;

    if not one_flag and huuse=1 then one_flag = 1;

    if one_flag then OUTPUT;   * want all rows in group starting at first huuse=1;
  end;
run;
```

Because the looping is explicit and never reaches the TOP of the program with in the loop, there is no need to `RETAIN` the flag variable, nor reset it.  Program variables that are not retained are reset automatically at the top of the program, and the top of the program is only reached at the start of the `BY` group.  Learn more about this programming construct in the SGF 2013 paper ["The Magnificent DO"](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/126-2013.pdf), Paul M. Dorfman

Comment: Your code looks like it will eliminating the opposite set of records from what was asked. You are deleting once the first 1 is seen instead of outputting once the first 1 is seen.

Comment: Yes! Worked perfectly. Thank you not only for the answer, but for the guidance and suggestion for further reading so I can learn more.  I'd been looking at another article yesterday and saw the Do loop of Whitlock, but I couldn't understand their explanation. Your explanation was great.

Answer (score 0):

Your source and result are same :-)
But if I understood your question correctly the solution is quite simple with a retain solution. I add 2 lines to the example to make it clear that I understood correctly.

The code with example table:

```
    data test; 
    id=1;huuse=0;days=4;output;  
    id=1;huuse=0;days=3;output;  
    id=1;huuse=1;days=12;output;    
    id=1;huuse=1;days=1;output;  
    id=1;huuse=2;days=15;output;  
    id=2;huuse=1;days=13;output;  
    id=2;huuse=0;days=16;output;  
    id=2;huuse=1;days=18;output;  
    id=2;huuse=0;days=44;output;
    id=3;huuse=0;days=1;output;
    id=3;huuse=1;days=2;output;
    run;

    data test_output;
    set test;
    retain keep_id -1;
    if (keep_id ne id and huuse ne 0) then keep_id=id;
    if keep_id = id then output;
    run;


    /* the results:
    id  huuse   days
    1   1   12  1
    1   1   1   1
    1   2   15  1
    2   1   13  2
    2   0   16  2
    2   1   18  2
    2   0   44  2
    3   1   2   3
    */
```

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. And thank you for the solution.